# How to resolve Input resource must exist (reader is in 'strict' mode) Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-stream

I'm reading a file from AWS S3 using `resourceLoader.getResource` in my Spring Batch application but I'm getting the below exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input resource must exist (reader is in 'strict' mode): class path resource [s3://myProduct/app/dev/product/input1]
```

I tried multiple solutions like using `PathResource` and other approaches but nothing worked out. Can someone please help me to resolve this issue? Please find my `reader` method below:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemReader<String> fileReader() {

    String bucketName = "myProduct";
    String key = "app/dev/product/input1";

    FlatFileItemReader reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
    reader.setResource(resourceLoader.getResource("s3://" +bucketName + "/" +key));
    reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper());


    return reader;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your `resourceLoader`? I assume it's spring's ResourceLoader, I guess it does not suit you. You can test other `Resource`, like `UrlResource`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more, I am getting the same exception and not sure what issue is caused by ResourceLoader.